# Want to remove the selected item from Listview

Tags: android

I have used a List and an Arrayadapter to put strings in a Listview.  Now I want to remove the selected Item.  I have tried the following code, but it's not working well. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
TextView t1;
String[] temp;
mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
final List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(temp);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
                                   wordList);
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       int index = mylist.getSelectedItemPosition();
       int count=mylist.getCount();
       for(int i=0;i<=count;i++) {
           if (index >= 0) {
               t1.setText(wordList.remove(index));
           }
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       } 
   }
});
```

Here's more source code:

```
    public class Edit extends Activity {
        SharedPreferences sharedpref;
        ListView mylist;
        String[] temp;
        String name, 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        Button save, delete, cancel;
        TextView t1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.edit);
            mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel1);
            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save1);
            delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete1);
            t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            sharedpref = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            name = sharedpref.getString("Visible_selected", "");

            String delimiter = "\n";
            temp = name.split(delimiter);

            mylist.setItemsCanFocus(true);
            mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
             final List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(temp);  

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, wordList);
            mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
            save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        private String getSelectedItemOfList;
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             getSelectedItemOfList = sortedList.get(arg2).getStr_movieParam();


                }
            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Here's my updates code:

```
enter code here
```

delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         adapter.remove(getSelectedItemOfList);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions =mylist.getCheckedItemPositions();
                if(checkedPositions.get(arg2)==true){
                getSelectedItemOfList = (String) mylist.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                t1.append(getSelectedItemOfList.toString()+"\n");}
            }
        });
```

Comment: is this giving any error or exception

Comment: no..Its not showing any error..

Comment: what button? how does "simple_list_item_multiple_choice" look like?
how do you know which have been selected?
You are showing such a little thing. What i normally do is delete from my arraylist, and then make a new adapter, set it to the list view, and call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: set onitemclick for the list and not for the button

Comment: @sharath G ..ya i can do as you said like onitem for list..,but i want show the changes when i click the delete button..

Comment: then you have to save the list item clicked which we get from the onitemclick of the listview and next when you click the button remove it from the arrayadapter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to implement the onitemclickListener and get the item id and delete the item clicked in the arrayadapter and next call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            String value = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            adapter.remove(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();               
        }
    });
```

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.3 => Here .remove(value) and .notifyDataSetChanged() are adapter class methods not AdapterView<?> methods. For example if the Adapter class name is ProductAdapter and it's object name is prodAdapter then Product prod = (Product) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); prodAdapter.remove(prod); prodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `OnItemClickListener()` for the `listview` so that when you select/click any list item you will get name of selected item then you can perform deletion operation.

Try this.

```
    mylist.OnItemClickListener(listenerOflistView);

private OnItemClickListener listenerOflistView = new OnItemClickListener() {
    private String getSelectedItemOfList;

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View view1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getSelectedItemOfList = mylist.get(pos).toString(); // here you will get selected item name.
      }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt use you the above code..its shows me an error in sorted list..:(

Comment: why is it so? Can you please post complete source code so that i can suggest something.

Comment: Not in logcat...Its shows me to create a localVariable..SortedList is a kinda property rite?

Comment: I have change my post SortedList is list which I am using in my app.plz update your code

Comment: please post your code so that we can help you in one or the other way

Comment: I have posted my entire code..But stil am getting the error even after i made changes to mylist.get(pos).toString();

Comment: what is the local variable that is showing error and where did you post the code?
i found the code with no necessary modifications.
can you post the error please

Comment: I think you are getting error bcoz you are trying to use listener inside listener.Instead of that uses separate listener for delete and listview.And declare `getSelectedItemOfList` as global variable so that you can use it in listener of delete button.

Comment: Ya..i have used separate listener..And i have used this..adapter.remove(getSelectedItemOfList);adapter.notifyDataSetchange();..but it shows me force close..

Comment: mylist.setonitem{getSelectedItemOfList = (String) mylist.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    t1.append(getSelectedItemOfList.toString()+"\n");}}

Comment: Plz remove `getSelectedItemOfList` from your wordList and assign new list to adapter.

Comment: delete.setonclick{getSelectedItemOfList);adapter.notifyDataSetchange();}...am using this one

Comment: See what you have to do is you have to compare `getSelectedItemOfList` with your list.Then remove that item form your list and create new adapter and assign that list(i.e. updated list) that's it.

Comment: adapter1.add (mylist.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
      adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
      mylist.setAdapter(adapter1); i couldnt update the list with selected item..

Answer (score 1):

see this code which help you to understand how to remove items in listview.

```
private ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ListView myListView;
private int getSelectedIndex = -1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    students.add("rahim");
    students.add("karim");
    students.add("sumon");
    students.add("rakib");
    students.add("porag");
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, students);
    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello " + students.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivity.this.getSelectedIndex = position;
            for (int i = 0; i < myListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if(position == i ){
                    myListView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }else{
                    myListView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }


        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            if(this.getSelectedIndex!=-1){
                students.remove(this.getSelectedIndex);
                this.getSelectedIndex = -1;

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to do this (the really best way is a custom adapter) is to keep a copy of your arraylist of items in your class.  Then when delete is called remofve the item form your copy of the arraylist and re-init the listview.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i want to tell you that code you have written is wrong...
May be you want the context menu  on listview..

if you are getting the position of selected item then you can have

```
adapter.removeItem(adapter.getItem(position));
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

may this help you

Comment: maybe we want delete not by the position but by the itemid that we set him.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                private String getSelectedItemOfList;
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     getSelectedItemOfList = sortedList.get(arg2).getStr_movieParam();
        }
    });
```

with

```
 mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                private String getSelectedItemOfList;
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     getSelectedItemOfList = sortedList.get(arg2).getStr_movieParam();
        }
    });
```

and

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 adapter.remove(getSelectedItemOfList );
adapter.notifydatasetChanged

        }
    });
```

check this one

Comment: See my updated code above..am not using wordlist now..simply using arrayadapter with listview..i can get the selected item from mylist.setonitem but when i click delete to remove it from adapter..its shows force close

Comment: once please post your new code again as a new comment please (if you dont mind)

Comment: Is there any other way to create a new adapter and replace the listview elements with those new adapter values?

Comment: @SharathG You are making mistake while getting selected item please read my post carefully

Comment: hey akshay..
Is there any necessity to get the particular value of the item.
The person is just intersted in removing the particular item that is clicked.Doesnt it mean that we just need to get the position rather than getting the data over there??
so i feel 
    getSelectedItemOfList = arg2 ;
is sufficient.
what do you say?

Comment: @Suji we are having notifydatasetChanged which is used to refresh the list when there is any modification in the items in the list.
so there might be no need to create any other adapter for this.

Comment: @sharath n akshay..I have updated as said using notifydatasetchanged..ill update the code here in the name of update3..pls see to it n give your solutions..

Comment: You are trying to remove all the elements from the adapter list.
I think that's not the one you require.
You even have a checkbox in your list view?

Comment: Sry please i made a mistake..I tel u clearly..the item which i get selected should remove from the list..And i have a checkbox in my listview by using simple_list_item_multiple_choice in adapter command..now i want to remove the items stored in getSelectedItemOfList..

Comment: You are using multiselection of checkboxes?

Comment: adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, temp); this one am using..

Comment: yes i understood it. 
use something like
SparseBooleanArray selectedPos = getListView()
        .getCheckedItemPositions(); or try checking the links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

Try working with this code in the http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/

Answer (score 0):

public class ListTest extends Activity {

```
String selectedItem;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView l1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_test);

  l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsvSign);

    newList.add("Android");
    newList.add("iOS");
    newList.add("Mac");
    newList.add("Windows");
    newList.add("Linux");;
    Collections.sort(newList);
    adapter = new new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,newList);
    l1.setAdapter(adapter);  


  l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {            
         selectedItem = l1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();           
       RemoveItem(selectedItem);

    }
});  
protected void RemoveItem(String item) {
    newList.remove(item);
    adp2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try working code:                          `listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(position));
 mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );`