# android studio delete from listivew

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove and refresh from Listview using CustomAdapter using the coding below

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SubjectData subjectData = arrayList.get(position);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.notifications_list, null);

        listView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationlist);


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String item = subjectData.notice_id.toString();
                arrayList.remove(item);
                listView.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Adam, can you provide information about where and how did you create your adaper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `adapter.notifyDataChanged()`

Comment: i did try adding adapter.notifyDataChanged() and the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  after remove your item.

[You can follow this answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946733/want-to-remove-the-selected-item-from-listview)