# How can we use two listview of Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application. On the result page there is a button. By clicking the button I want to show a filter option to the users so that they can filter the data !

[SampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR3x4.png)

I am not able to create this layout ,what i have to use for this to create the layout

Please help me with this

After using two listview the design is scattered look in the image 
[image: TwoListViews]

Comment: may be navigation drawer might help you. keep one listview in drawer and second in fragment.

Comment: Tell me what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @PiyushGupta i tried this design by using two listview but it is not working for me .First issue is that i want to add two button on tops right as for clear and apply .and when i am using two listview the design is scattered

Comment: When you click on Filter new activity is opening in different screen ??

Comment: no i don't want to open any new activity

Comment: Then your sample showing that you have back navigation icon and its seems new sceen

Comment: i don't want navigation drawer i just want to open this layout in dialog having two buttons of clear and apply

Comment: Ok Then you need to make a custom View in which you need to add two buttons on top most and below that two listViews and inflate that view to Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]In LinearLayout of Horizontal orientation, embedd the first ListView and assign a layout width of 50dp to 100dp(in bretween),Embedd the second ListView to the right of first ListView in the LinearLayout and assign width wrap_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Now design ListItems of both the lists as per your requirements.

After that relate the itemclickListener of your first ListView to the Second one like this :
       ListView lv1,lv2;

```
 lv1.setAdapter(new FirstListAdapter);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position==0){
                lv2.setAdapter(new AdapterA);
            }else if(position==1){
                lv2.setAdapter(new AdapteB);
            }

        }
    });
```

Based on the selection of first ListView Item you have to set the adapter of second ListView adapter.
This is the basic idea rest do make sure that you clear listviews on time.

Comment: how we will relate them and i want apply and clear button also .and should i use dialog to show this filter or should i use something else

Comment: what do you want to filter ?.... is your filtered result is displayed on the side list ...... is the first listview's item are filter options

Comment: this is exactly what i need but i am not getting it please elaborate more so that i can understand it and use it

Comment: i have a result page on that there is a filter option on click of that i want to show a layout like this after clicking on the check boxes from the second list i want user to press apply button then i will send http request

Comment: see first list is main category and second listview is sub category .

Comment: It is very simple.. all you need to do is make a adapter ... let say AdapterA which will extend BaseAdapter.. design a listitem for the same consisting of a checkbox and a textview adjacent to each other ..come back to adapter a class... in its getView do add this thing holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(). to make checkbox clickable. now when you want to use APPLY button in main activity.... now in the Button's on click listener add this...

Comment: Continued previous comment

SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    if (checked.get(i)) {
        // Do something
    }
}

Comment: Also CHECK THIS LINK FOR REFERENCE
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview

Comment: I am not able add 2 buttons on the top right of the listviews with a logo and i don't want to use dialog to show this filter any other thing that we can use

Comment: Use actionbar items or toolbar items(in case of lollipop)...... Please +1 the answer if it helped you

Comment: will u please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679726/add-scrollview-and-highlight-on-a-linear-layout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will help you. I Hope!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is creating a custom dialog.
You can create the dialog with a linear layout and add all the CheckedTextView you need.

```
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Your title");
CheckedTextView ctv=(CheckedTextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ctv);
Button ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn_blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
});
dialog.show();
```

You will need to add to this code the listener for the checkedtextview and then pass as variable the status of those checks.