# Android ListView with one Button

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my Fragment and I want to have  one button like "Get checked items" that checks what items have been clicked. Previously I used setOnItemClickListener,and it showed what item is clicked right now, but it seems as for button I need to use OnClick.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.feat,container,false);
     ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    list.setItemChecked(4, true);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view ;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int postition=(Integer)v.getTag();
    //What should be here?
}
```

Comment: You can get the checked items using `list.getCheckedItemPositions()`. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19414593/1240523

Comment: when adding that piece of code into OnClick, it can't resolve list.
While if I add that into OnCreateView it won't work with the click of the button

Comment: I can't help with programming principles, but your list needs to be put into the namepsace of the activity,

Comment: Thanks, the link you posted worked for me, but it's  working  only when I click on the item, and I don't know how to use it with OnClick method

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store the positions of checked items in a global int array and check the array on Button click. Maybe not the smartest but looks like fastest solution to me?