# How to get checked items from ListView?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, listview

I have a custom `listview`  with **checkBoxes** and populates it with data from `List<>`. I was thinking how to receive the items which are checked and I basically couldn't find the solution. Is it possible to make it with the `ListView` like this or should I make a custom `ListView`? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am trying to deal with:

```
         public string content;
         ListView productsListView; 

         List<Product> _productsList = ProductsFromXml();

        //list for checked items (not yet)
        List<Product> checkedProducts = new List<Product>();

        //creating a ListView within our products
        productsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        productsListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, _productsList);
        productsListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
```

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on your `Product` object like `bool Checked` and set it to `true/false` on the `ItemClick` event.

Then you can go through the list and see which items are selected.

[This Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/use_an_arrayadapter/) shows you how to listen to click events for a `ListView` backed by an `ArrayAdapter`.

Your `Activity` will need to inherit from  `ListActivity` and then you can override

```
OnListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

and use the `int position` parameter to index the `Products` list and se the value to `true/false` to indicate selection.

Comment: I have a class called `Product`. So I should create a bool property there?

Comment: And if I want to make my ListView scrollable?