# I am making an app and getting issue in check box selection

Tags: android

Whenever I unchecked any one check box button then last one also being unchecked so I am confuse to understand that what is main issue. I think
it is being recycled.

```
private ArrayList<MusterRollAttendanceMaster> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private ViewHolder holder = null;;

    public MusterGridAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<MusterRollAttendanceMaster> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.list = list;
        inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewTag")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                int count = list.size();
                boolean isAllChecked = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    if (!(list.get(i).getSelected())) {
                        isAllChecked = false;
                    }

                holder.chk.setChecked(isAllChecked);

            }

        });

        holder.chk
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                            boolean arg1) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(view.isChecked());
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            if (!list.get(i).getSelected())
                                checkBox_header.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        int p = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            if (list.get(i).getSelected())
                                p++;
                        }
                        if (p == list.size())
                            checkBox_header.setChecked(true);
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, holder.chk);
        String part2;
        holder.chk.setTag(position);
        holder.jcn.setText(part2);

        holder.chk.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private TextView jcn;
        private TextView applicant;
        private CheckBox chk;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        count = list.size();
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its problem specifically created by cell reusing of listview. Check the following link this will definitely help you

http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

[Android Click on listItem checks wrong checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010623/android-click-on-listitem-checks-wrong-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

Dimension at top:

```
private ArrayList<String> checkedNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your inflate view:

```
if (checkedNames.contains(holder.chk.getText().toString()))
    holder.chk.setChecked(true);
else
    holder.chk.setChecked(false);

holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
     @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
       String name = buttonView.getText().toString(); //or declare your checkbox final
       if (isChecked)
          checkedNames.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
       else
          checkedNames.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

and when inflating your listview item it should be:

```
 convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save `CheckBox` state in model class as boolean. When you change `CheckBox` state(checked or unchecked) also change boolean value in model class and just call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It will make adapter know that you have changed the `CheckBox` state. Happy Coding.